# How to use WPF user control in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I have  developed a WPF user control and I want to use it in ASP.net.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. ASP.NET and WPF are completely different technologies. Best you could do is provide an XBAP application from your ASP.NET application, which is downloaded and run client side as a WPF application. Even if you convert it to Silverlight, it's still running client-side, with the advantage that Silverlight is a lighter runtime and is available on some non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it directly.
You can either create an XBAP or you convert the control to Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can if you use it in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

simply make a little "Silverlight" application and explicitly place on your ASP page. probably you can't do in placing wpf in ASP because the compiler is not teach to read Xbap with knowledge base (extension) of ASP XD

Comment: You can't use XAML in ASP.Net because browsers aren't WPF renderers.

Comment: exactly, also while the compiler call to work is ask it to built asp but not wpf(xaml)

Comment: Thx to @SLaks reminds =D XBAP is an apps it is silverlight not wpf .yesterday rush off forgotten to correction ~.~